# Qt two serial ports send and receive

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qt5

I have two objects of the class `Foo` in my main class `MainWindow`, which use a serial connection between two FTDI breakout boards to read and write serial data. I've checked this setup via a terminal and it works.

In my main class, I'm trying to send a QByteArray from `FooA` to `FooB`, but `received` is empty when executing `testConnection()`. I've checked the serial connection with an additional FTDI breakout connected parallel to the FooB port, and I saw in the terminal that the data is only sent by FooA as it exits `testConnection()`. If I execute the function again, `received` ist filled with the string `"Test"`. The slot is called when a button is clicked.

I've tried emitting a signal from `FooB` when `m_serial->readyRead` ist fired and connecting it to another slot in `MainWindow`, but the problem persists.

Am I missing something here or how can I solve this issue without having to click two times to receive the message?

The class Foo looks something like this:

```
#include <QSerial>

class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    void writeData(const QByteArray &data);
    QString readData();

private:
    QWidget *m_parent;
    QSerialPort *m_serial;
};    

void DataLink::writeData(const QByteArray &data)
{
    m_serial->clear();
    m_serial->write(data);
}

QString DataLink::readData()
{
    m_serial->waitForReadyRead(1500);
    return QString(m_serial->readAll()).simplified();
}
```

and the MainWindow class looks something like this:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include "foo.h"

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void testConnection();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui = nullptr;
    Foo *fooA = nullptr;
    Foo *fooB = nullptr;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow), fooA(new Foo()), fooB(new Foo())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::testConnection()
{
    fooA->writeData("Test");
    QString received = fooB->readData();
    QDebug() << received << endl;
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the code very carefully: try using signals and slots, and don't use *waitForXxxxx* methods in GUI application (at least not main thread).

Comment: More specifically, since you are having issues: connect every signal of QSerialPort to a slot and add debug prints into all of them. This will help you understand what is happening, so you can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked hyde's comment and solved the problem via a workaround: Before exiting `testConnection` I start a timer which executes a slot to read the serial data, with a small delay this solution works and doesn't block the GUI too much.